# Control formatting of blob.getAs("application/pdf") in Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, html-to-pdf

When converting a webpage such as [this](https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/quiptic/1102/print) using Print to Pdf in Chrome, or from various Share Sheet elements in iOS, the pdf output is formatted to a single page like this: Output from Print to Pdf or iOS Share Sheet[image]

In Google Apps Script, converting the html to pdf using the code below results in a two page pdf: Output from blob.getAs("application/pdf")[image]

```
function mwe() {
  var url = "https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/quiptic/1102/print"
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var blob = html.getBlob();
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("example");
}
```

Is there either a way of controlling the formatting when using blob.getAs() to output as the former, or a better method I can use in Apps Script for converting a webpage to pdf?

Comment: Use options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197358

Comment: Those paramaters seem to be part of the export link for a Google Sheet item, I don't understand how they can be applied to a generic webpage?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Apps Script - Convert HTML with styling to PDF and attach to an email - Create a PDF blob from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690350/google-apps-script-convert-html-with-styling-to-pdf-and-attach-to-an-email-c)

Shows how to create a PDF from a blob from HTML. I do not have enough points to add this as a comment rather than a standalone answer.